# Rodando a aplicação da pagina que esta sendo editada

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Quando eu usava o Visual Studio anterior, ASP NET 4.xx, quando eu rodava a aplicação F5, o sistema abria a pagina que eu estava editando, agora, no visual 2017 (ASP Net Core), ele sempre abre a Home. Existe a possibilidade de voltar abrir a pagina que estou editando?